# Does Angular 5+ has similar global variable data like web.config in asp.net?

Tags: web-config, environment-variables, global-variables, angular5

In asp.net web application, we can save some settings or key attribute in web.config like **database connection string, key variable like salt, api url or ftp location which won't be exposed to outside user**, while when working in Angular 5 project,

1. where can we store these information?
2. I noticed there is an **environment.ts** file in environment folder
       but not sure **whatever stored in this environment.ts file would be
       exposed to outside?**
3. And also there is a **environment.prod.ts**  file, if my setting on
   dev would be same as prod, does it mean we need to copy everything
   from **environment.ts** to **environment.prod.ts** file?